# Open fragment from a fragment with cardview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can I open a fragment from a fragment with Cardview?  I have a list of Cardview in fragment_home.xml and when i click in one of those want to show in another fragment.
Here is what i have so far.

fragment_home.xml

```
       <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvCocktails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Cocktails">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCocktails"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="115dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cocktail"
                android:src="@drawable/cocktail_color"
                android:translationY="-15dp"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintBounds" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ivCocktails"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/cocktail"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                tools:ignore="SpUsage,TextSizeCheck" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public CardView cocktails;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

    cocktails = view.findViewById(R.id.cvCocktails);
    cocktails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CocktailFragment cocktailFragment = new CocktailFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_home,cocktailFragment,null)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
    return  view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

When i compile the app and click on Cocktail Cardview i have this error. How can i fix this. Thank you.

> 

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.barapp, PID: 11805
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Cocktails(View) in a parent 
    or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class 
    android.widget.RelativeLayout
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:6302)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6259)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: remove android:onClick="Cocktails"

Comment: provide more details, like screenshots, also provide where is R.id.fragment_home and where did you add HomeFragment ?